# T-SQL: Get max numeric value in char field having both numbers and letters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, numeric, isnumeric

In a SQL Server 2008 database table I have a char field that has both numbers and letters. I.e.:

```
TST
842
UUT
124
674
XTM
763
```

I need to find the maximum **integer** in that field. So in the above example I would return "842".

I know how to test for whether the value is numeric or not (`ISNUMERIC()`function), but I can't figure out how, using that test, to return the maximum integer value.

Comment: First of all, do not use `ISNUMERIC` - use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_PARSE` function - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manub22/archive/2013/12/24/use-new-try-parse-instead-of-isnumeric-sql-server-2012.aspx

Comment: Thanks, gotqn, but as you can see from the multiple answers below, `ISNUMERIC()` works just fine. (In my particular case, at least. There are always exceptions!)

Comment: @gotqn: Since the OP is asking for SQL Server 2008. Is `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_PARSE` are available in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: is it possible to have a `.`? if so `isnumeric` may not give you the correct answer if you actually need interger and not just highest number and `TRY_Convert` may truncate the `.`

Comment: @Arulkumar No, `try_convert` was introduced in 2012 afaik.

Comment: And there you have your exception! :) I will only have numbers and letters in that field in my table so the `ISNUMERIC()` check works.

Comment: Try_Parse converts "1,1" to 11 which is an error for my case: select TRY_PARSE('1,1' as int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(yourcol) FROM T WHERE ISNUMERIC(yourcol)=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT MAX(field) 
FROM   table 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(field) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use an outer query to get the max from the set of integers:

```
select MAX(your_char) from (select your_char from table where ISNUMERIC(your_char) = 1) sub
```

or actually this should work too:

```
select MAX(your_char) from t where ISNUMERIC(your_char) = 1
```